# Android "adjustPan" is sometimes not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-keypad

I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the Manifest file.
It works ok. But sometimes, this attribute is not working, it is working like nothing is set in the Manifest file.

In the screen, I create a listView with EditText inside. When I click on the EditText the keyboard is shock and I can't type anything.

Comment: I found the answer is when I set window soft input mode in another screen, it will affect to the new screen.

Comment: what does that even mean?